# Assigning a function to a variable in C++

Tags: c++

What happens if you assign a function to a variable as shown below

```
unsigned char uchHeaderVer; 
uchHeaderVer = GetCodec(Page.Version);
```

```
BYTE CWAV::GetCodec(BYTE byVersion)
{
    RecorderInfoMap::iterator it;

    if ((it = m_mapRecInfo.find(byVersion)) != m_mapRecInfo.end()) {
        return (BYTE) ((*it).second.nCodec);
    } else {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Version is of type BYTE and is stored in a typedef struct

Comment: What's the return type of `GetCodec`?

Comment: What is `Version`? Likely `Version` is an object identifier, and this would assign the *result* of calling `GetCodec` to `uchHeaderVer`.

Comment: `BYTE` is usually a `typedef` for `unsigned char`, so, the function gets called, returns a value and that gets stored in the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if you assign a function to a variable as shown below

You *aren't* assigning a function to a variable. You are *calling* a function, and assigning the result to that variable.

You haven't shown what `BYTE` is, but it is very likely to be a type alias for either `unsigned char` (or possibly `char`).

You can't assign a function to a variable, because functions aren't objects. You can only assign pointers to functions to variables, e.g.

```
BYTE (*pGetCodec)(BYTE) = &CWAV::GetCodec;
auto pGetCodec2 = &CWAV::GetCodec;
using GetCodecF = BYTE (*)(BYTE);
GetCodecF pGetCodec3 = &CWAV::GetCodec;
```

Comment: To assign a function to a variable you'd have to do something like this, right? `void *fun = CWAV::GetCodec;`

Comment: @alonkh2 `BYTE (*f) (BYTE) = CWAV::GetCodec;` is a function pointer. You cannot assing a function to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Every function, if not defined as returning `void`, must return a value, the type of returned value is declared at the beginning of function declaration.

```
  int some_func(){
// ^^ This is the type of returned variable.
      return 1;
  }
```

What happens in your case is simply assigning the returned value of `GetCodec(Page.Version)` to `uchHeaderVer`. And if the types `uchHeaderVer` and `GetCodec(Page.Version)` don't match, a conversion will happen, and if the conversion is not possible, you will get a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

If the function returns a value and it matches (or can be casted) the variable type, then this value will be assigned to this variable, if not the code will not compile
Example :

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘int’ in assignment
```

If the function returns `void` also you will get an error :

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```